# Making A Case for Multithreading AND Multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, parallel-processing, raspberry-pi

I have a RPI3B+ working on a project with 30 or so different IO modules. The hardware resources are fixed and cannot be upgraded, so we've got 4 cores. Among the IOs are a keyboard, motors on a HAT, LEDs both i2c and PWM driven, a screen to display images and video, an IMU, various binary GPIOs, sound out, etc and more. There's a lot. It's a big ol' art installation.

Some of these IOs are a quick fire and forget, and others must have their state managed by the program (ie some servos must be moved more quickly/slowly than others, writing their PWM values at different times, lots of sleep()). We're not truly IO bound as the most outputs don't need to return with an input, but if I were to create a process for every one, that would create a lot of overhead. Maybe threading/async?

Well, some of the tasks to drive the outputs are more CPU intensive than others, and this could compound at times when some or all of them are being driven at the same time. Not all are critical to the function, but some absolutely cannot afford to be interrupted. So for example:

I have an IMU that keeps track of the project's position in space and in order to keep the whole project from falling flat the IMU's output gets mapped to a balancing servo. That is absolutely critical.

It would also be critical not to miss inputs from the USB keypad. But with many of the LEDs and motors we need to drive, and they can afford to lag a bit if the program becomes CPU bound. So, maybe multiprocessing?

*MOST* of the modules driving IOs don't need to be aware of the state of the rest of them, so the program can initialize them with a value and they would do their thing in time and let the rest of the application run.

SO, with all that said could I create a few processes, and placing the more critical IO in their own process while organizing possible CPU-intensive problem makers into threads in a separate process. Is this a good case to use both?

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong tool for the job :)

If you want any sort of real-time or even near real-time control (motors reacting to IMU), you need to ditch a single-board computer (SBC). SBCs often have very limited processing power and run an OS and multiple different software instances in the background. by the time the CPU has time to process your requests (even if they are defined as interrupts and hence async), it is already too late (ask me how I know ...).

You need to use a microcontroller (something like the pi pico would be more than good enough for the job if you want to stay within the same ecosystem) to do all the hard work and then the pi can do the more computationally expensive bits of the code (I don't think your case has any such code, but for robotics applications things like mapping and navigation are offloaded to the pi while the MCUs do things like reading the IMU, motor encoders, controlling the motor PWM, etc. and sending that information back to the pi so it knows the state of the robot). This is because an MCU runs only ONE program and often has dedicated hardware functionality for the exact use cases you mention (balancing robot). The pi pico even has programmable IO that deals with tasks like driving LEDs without ever needing to process anything on the CPU; just map a segment of memory to represent your LED colors/brightness values and the PIO can pump out those values on a few pins automagically.

Back to your original question: multi-processing is hardly ever the answer, it is SIGNIFICANTLY slower than multi-threading. the situation you describe is I/O bound, not CPU bound (if you can run some benchmarks, I'll guarantee you that'll be the case) which should be easily solved by multi-threading. Furthermore, you may want to look into using Cython to create an optimized version of your code if you are truly CPU-bound. As long as you're careful with your processing and pass Numpy arrays as memory views to Cython, you can even release the GIL and directly work on shared memory using different cores/threads. Again, this is achieved via multi-threading, not multi-processing. If you need performance, stay away from multi-processing as it requires lots of message passing and memory copies.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response! Believe it or not I opted for using an SBC to limit the weight on the balanced object. Due to some insane constraints that I shaint get too deep into, the "brain" and components are all going to be onboard the balanced payload, and with an MCU, which I usually prefer to work with, I would need so many peripheral add-ons which add to the weight. 

But I guess you're saying to just use the MCU to run the motors and LEDs, and have the SBC handle everything else. I would still have the same issue with IO concurrency on an MCU though.

Comment: are there any really heavy computations that need to happen? By that I mean really really heavy computations like pathfinding, localization, image processing, etc. Modern MCUs are very powerful and can do what you want with a fraction of the weight (just take 3D printers for example, they run inverse kinematics and real-time motor drive in multiple axes using something like an STM32). if not then you don't need an SBC. So far the only thing that "requires"(not really) an SBC is getting mouse and keyboard (USB) input which can still be done on an MCU.

Comment: @CarlCampbell I have many years of experience in both robotics, real-time data processing, and Python programming, but if you don't want to take my word for it, I made a more detailed post here about how you can speed up your code using multi-threading here (I know it's a bit long but it's definitely worth reading):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77325423/increasing-cpu-usage-with-python-during-for-loops/77334010#77334010